# Not getting the full audio into text

Tags: python

I have tried the below code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
filename = "demo.wav"

with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
    audio_data = r.record(source)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio_data)
    print(text)
```

from [here](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/using-speech-recognition-to-convert-speech-to-text-python)

It gives the output as follows

```
result2:
{   'alternative': [   {   'confidence': 0.92995489,
                           'transcript': 'talking nonsense'},
                       {'transcript': 'you talking nonsense'},
                       {'transcript': 'are you talking nonsense'},
                       {'transcript': 'Divya talking nonsense'},
                       {'transcript': 'are talking nonsense'}],
    'final': True}
talking nonsense
```

But the audio file contains :
"I believe you're just talking nonsense"

Why it is not giving the whole audio??
Please help me to figure it out..

Thankuu

Comment: Seems like the genuine output of the model. These models can miss some parts of speech especially if the pronunciation is not right or if there is heavy background noise. You might have to work around those issues to get near perfect outputs from the model.

Comment: I don't know how to upload media file here but it is available in the link

Comment: So any other option sir to get the proper output???

Comment: Your link directs to an article.

Comment: Yes from that article I have taken code and the audio file

Answer (score 1):

The function `recognize_google` "performs speech recognition using the Google Speech Recognition API."

Speech recognition can obvioulsy never be 100% exact with the input.

As stated in the documentation of the function [recognize_gogle](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/c5bb4a34fb0936eaf848f403652e5c49a9b22a92/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L859):

> Returns the most likely transcription if `show_all` is false (the default). Otherwise, returns the raw API response as a JSON dictionary.
>
> Raises a `speech_recognition.UnknownValueError` exception if the speech is unintelligible. Raises a `speech_recognition.RequestError` exception if the speech recognition operation failed, if the key isn't valid, or if there is no internet connection.

The first lines ("result2:" and the model) that you see in your code are the output (not the result) of the function `recognize_gogle` (See source line [#918](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/c5bb4a34fb0936eaf848f403652e5c49a9b22a92/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L918)).

The last line ("talking nonsense") is the actual result of function `recognize_gogle` which is based in confidence values of the different hypothesis (See source lines [#921](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/c5bb4a34fb0936eaf848f403652e5c49a9b22a92/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L921)ff)

If you want to get the full result add the argument `show_all=True` to `recognize_gogle`. See example below.

The following example shows how to test it without having to record a wavefile. The wavefile is generated by `espeak` (present in most linux distros).

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
import subprocess
import pprint

wave_file = '/path/to/your/wavefile.wav'
text = "I believe you are just talking nonsense"
proc = subprocess.Popen(['espeak', '-a', '200', '-s', '130', '-w', wave_file, text])
proc.communicate()

recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile(wave_file) as source:
    audio_data = recognizer.record(source)

if audio_data is not None:
    recognized_text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio_data, show_all=True)
    pprint.pprint(recognized_text)
```

```json
{'alternative': [{'confidence': 0.88625956,
                  'transcript': "I'm talking nonsense"},
                 {'transcript': 'talking nonsense'},
                 {'transcript': "I'm talking London"},
                 {'transcript': 'talking London'},
                 {'transcript': "I'm talking now"}],
 'final': True}
```

Comment: It gives me this error```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'espeak'```

Comment: @Manvi: Is `espeak` installed in your system? For Debian/Ubuntu do `apt-get install espeak`.

Comment: It gives me now an empty list ```[]```

Comment: @Manvi: Do you mean an empty list as value of the key 'alternative'? Please check if the 'wave_file' has been properly created in the given place (evtl. modify the path) which the given content. Try another content in the variable 'text'

Comment: Yes it is created but still it returns an empty list ```[]```

Comment: But it's ok I got the solution for this..